# Window manipulation using java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, cross-platform

I want to make a program that would be able to manipulate the desktop based on user input commands (Preferably by voice, but... baby steps). Similar to Windows Speech Recognition, or Cortana.

I would like to make this as easy as possible to use and set up etc. For this reason I had planned on writing it in Java so that it would be cross-platform, and as simple as possible for users.

After looking further into how I would go about this, I saw mentioned here ([Manipulating windows from other applications in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386801/manipulating-windows-from-other-applications-in-java)) that I should use JNI.

I'm now wondering if (as mentioned in the top comment) it would be easier if I were to switch to C++ as using JNI might negate the cross-platform capability benefits of Java?

Or if possible, would it be possible to have the program select the appropriate JNI classes automatically based on the operating system?

**In short: Does JNI negate the benefits of Java cross-platform compatibility?**

*Sorry if this post is a bit confusing. I've quite a few questions so this may seem a bit all over the place.*

Comment: I think you'll have a hard time to even properly specify a good cross-platform desktop-manipulation program, as every operating system has different desktop metaphors, different ways to launch programs etc., and using the minimal common denominators is usually very limiting.

Comment: So you're saying it would be best to just pick one operating system for now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many Operating System specific tasks cannot be done platform independent. But what Java already does a lot and JNI allows you to do too is that you can have different native binaries for different platforms - and possibly a single Java API to use all of them platform-independent.

Going C++ has the disadvantage that you need to have multiple executables. With Java you could have just 1 that loads different native code.

Although if you need a lot of different native code to implement your idea, maybe it's easier to just implement it for just 1 platform directly in a language that has bindings to all the required native APIs. Like maybe C# for Windows and something else for other platforms?

Comment: So I would be able to design the program with just say Windows 7 in mind and then later add other packages for other operating systems? And a user would be able to download just the one version that would select the correct package itself, depending on the operating system?

If so, then that's just the answer I was looking for. I'll keep in mind what you said about C#, but I think I will try for Java for now.

A large goal for this is for it to be as user-friendly as possible, so allowing a single version would definitely be ideal.

Comment: @user3542347 It depends on how much can be handled in common code but if Java becomes just a launcher for almost entirely different programs it becomes pointless. I'd then prefer a platform specific installer & program & os integration. That's simpler for users because everything is tailored specifically for them & the download is smaller. Just need to pick the right one like so many programs do. You could use Java + JNI but if you want tight integration with Windows, I'd not recommend it. And C# is cross platform too (Mono), just all the windows APIs you need aren't. But at least they exist.

Comment: @user3542347 if you happen to be great at C++ go with it. You can write platform independent C/C++ too. Just needs to be compiled for each platform (but that's the same for JNI).

Comment: Thanks. You've been a great help. I'll definitely look more into other languages again. The plan was for a program that even the least technically adept would find easy to use, but I feel I should at least get the program working before I worry about simplicity. Thanks again.